# Pass role variable through $author (advanced_forum module?)

Tags: nodes

i'm trying to show last_post $author role in the advanced forum forum-list.

What i've discovered is that last_post appearance can be changed in advanced-forum.submitted.tpl.php, however the $author variable does not contain anything except 'topic' and 'time' according to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!forum!forum-submitted.tpl.php/7 which is not enough for me...

is there any way to add a "roles" variable $author var?

This is needed to code the username in relation with it's role (http://pastebin.com/9gDX2qi3 - under the (HERE AUTHOR ROLE_ID) part)